# URL encryption of an URL aliased asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, encryption, alias

The requirement is to URL encode the ASP.NET web page URL which is having Ektron Alias.
Its unable to get the aliased URl using context using HTTP Module.
So getting confused, kindly help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you show us some code for what you're doing at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved.
Added a small Utility class to the App_Code with a module config entry in ektron.
This [link](http://madskristensen.net/post/HttpModule-for-query-string-encryption.aspx) helped in solving it.

Thanks
Libin